# how to copy an attribute of an object to a vector?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, stdvector

I have a `vector<Person>` and want to extract the attribute name of each object, to a `vector<string>`. The for-each loop does it job correctly, but is there a nicer way to use something like `std::copy()` and tell him to use a specific method (in this case the `name()` getter) to copy the values into my `vector<string>`?

```
class Person {
  int a;
  string n;
public:
  Person(int age, string name) : a(age), n(name) {}
  int age() const { return a; }
  string name() const { return n; }
};

vector<Person> ppl = { Person(12, "Tim"), Person(21, "Tom") };
vector<string> names;

// question
// copy(ppl.begin(), ppl.end(), ????.name());

for (Person& p : ppl)
  names.push_back(p.name());

copy(names.begin(), names.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, ", "));
```

Comment: I think the range for is by far the cleaniest approach for such a simple task.

Comment: from this question I think you will LOVE functional programming

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter):

```
std::transform(std::begin(ppl), std::end(ppl),
               std::back_inserter(names),
               [](const Person& p) -> std::string { return p.name(); });
```

In the end though, it's still basically the same as what you already have.

Comment: I want to do more with the names. The `std::cout` was just to have a simple example to my problem.

Comment: `back_inserter` in general case means potential reallocations

Comment: @AndyT: You can use `reserve` to mitigate that, if it's an issue. In the general case, that would be more efficient than `resize` followed by assignment.

Comment: the equivalent for back_inserter for a set?

Comment: @EddyEkofo A [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) doesn't have a "back" or a "front" so it can't have front or back inserters. It does however have an [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) function which means you could use an [`std::insert_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator) as returned by the [`std::inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) function.

Answer (score 4):

A range-based `for` loop is usually the most straightforward way to do an arbitrary operation to each element of a container. There's also the [`transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) algorithm:

```
transform(
    ppl.begin(), 
    ppl.end(), 
    back_inserter(names),
    [](Person const & p){return p.name();}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<string> names(ppl.size());
transform(ppl.begin(), ppl.end(), names.begin(), [](const Person& p) { return p.name(); });
```

or for C++03:

```
transform(ppl.begin(), ppl.end(), names.begin(), mem_fun(&Person::name));
```